# Create one row from others rows

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem. I have data in a table that look like that :

```
route_id    route_short_name    route_long_name

AOUT1112E   12                  Direction Pont-Viau
AOUT1112O   12                  Direction Métro Cartier
JANV1212E   12                  Direction Pont-Viau
JANV1212O   12                  Direction Métro Cartier
JRAN1212E   12                  Direction Pont-Viau
JRAN1212O   12                  Direction Métro Cartier
```

I need the result to be like that :

12 - Direction Pont-Viau / Direction Métro Cartier

OR

12 - Direction Pont-Viau / Métro Cartier

I tought I may use two arrays but I'd like to do this in MySQL. Also, I got other routes in the table like route 13, 15, etc so it need to work in a SELECT ALL Anyone have any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: you'd need to instruct us how to join your routes together to give the expected data. Your route id's don't match and you are not providing "directions" for your route except for the "E" and "O" in the route_id...

Comment: Isn't that possible with `group_concat()`?

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin I didn't build this table... The problem is it need to work in a way that it will work with all other routes tables from other companies... that the problem.

Comment: Build it or not, we still need to understand how you want us to link the info together to get the result. For example, do we need to parse the ROUTE_ID to get AOUT out and link both AOUT rows together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine two strings, use `CONCAT()`. To join the values in a group, use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CONCAT(
        route_short_name,
        " - ",
        GROUP_CONCAT(route_long_name SEPARATOR ' / ')
    ) AS route_name
FROM 
    ...
GROUP BY
    route_short_name
```

It would return something like this:

```
SHORTNAME - LONGNAME1 / LONGNAME2 / LONGNAME3
```

The above would only return one row per `route_short_name`. To get them all, use a subquery:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT CONCAT(
        route_short_name, 
        " - ", 
        GROUP_CONCAT(route_long_name.b SEPARATOR " / "))
    FROM 
        your_table_name AS your_table_name_inner
    WHERE 
        your_table_name_inner.route_short_name = your_table_name_outer.short_name
    GROUP BY 
        your_table_name.route_short_name
) AS route_name
FROM
    your_table_name AS your_table_name_outer
```

The subquery is pretty much the same as the first example, except that it always returns a single row in the format `SHORTNAME - LONGNAME1 / LONGNAME2 / etc`. The outer query returns all records and for every record, the subquery is executed. It goes without saying that this is a heavier query than the first example.

---

On closer inspection, its seems that the `route_short_name` is actually quite irrelevant to the database structure, unlike what I assumed.

I've left the above answer, because it might help someone else.

If I understand correctly, you want to join two (not more, not less) records, where one has a `route_id` ending with an `E` and one with an `O`.

Assuming the following:

- The ID is always 8 characters + an `E` or `O`.
- There are always two records that belong together.

In that case:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CONCAT(a.route_short_name, ' - ', a.route_long_name, ' / ', b.route_long_name)
FROM
    your_table_name AS a
JOIN
    your_table_name AS b
ON
    LEFT(a.route_id, 8) = LEFT(b.route_id, 8)
AND
    a.route_id != b.route_id
```

This does the following:

1. Return the short name, a dash, long name 1, slash, long name 2.
2. Join based on the first 8 characters of the IDs (`LEFT(str, n)` returns the first *n* characters of a string).
3. The IDs may not be an exact match (which prevents joining with itself).

This might be rather slow (due to the use of `LEFT()`), but MySQL might have some black magic that optimizes things and indexes might help as well. Benchmark it on your real table.

Comment: +1 but it is worth mentioning, that formatting the output on database side is rather silly.